# `fio` does not timeout even specified?

Tags: centos7, filesystems, xfs, fio, hdd

```
# fio --name=random-write --directory=/mnt/test/ --ioengine=posixaio --rw=randwrite -bs=4k --numjobs=1 --size=4g -iodepth=1 -runtime=600 --time_based --end_fsync=1
random-write: (g=0): rw=randwrite, bs=(R) 4096B-4096B, (W) 4096B-4096B, (T) 4096B-4096B, ioengine=posixaio, iodepth=1
fio-3.7
Starting 1 process
random-write: Laying out IO file (1 file / 4096MiB)
Jobs: 1 (f=1): [w(1)][100.0%][r=0KiB/s,w=0KiB/s][r=0,w=0 IOPS][eta 00m:00s]
```

Any idea why it returned after 60 mins rather than 600 seconds that I set?

I checked `dmesg`, no error:

```
[Mon Mar  1 20:53:36 2021] XFS (sda2): Mounting V5 Filesystem
[Mon Mar  1 20:53:37 2021] XFS (sda2): Starting recovery (logdev: internal)
[Mon Mar  1 20:53:45 2021] XFS (sda2): Ending recovery (logdev: internal)
```

I ran the same command on another drive (a SSD instead) on the same box at the same time, and it finished on time and returned.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Anon yes latest gave me the same issue.  yes, double dashes are expected and they are fine.  not sure about whether there were a lot of I/O continuing be sent to the disk after time was up.  Shorter timeout same issue.  `libaio` same issue.  Haven't tried with `direct` and without `end_fsync`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is a related to my faulty SATA controller.  Replacing it solves the issue.